# ETL Package to automate Outlook attachment to SFTP location

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, outlook, etl

I am new to using ETL packages, can some one help me to understand how to setup tasks for automating file transfer from email attachments to SFTP server location ?

Thank you

Comment: it is very uncommon to have Office products on a server. you might want to consider targeting the SMTP server directly. I personally would attack this problem with .NET and a nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a third party tool, try out cloudmailin. https://www.cloudmailin.com/blog/what_are_S3_attachments
I followed a tutorial to do it in AWS and it worked. You can give it a try. https://rogave.com/upload-data-automatically-to-amazon-s3-from-outlook/